# Open graph problem: Showing wrong description of homepage while sharing on Facebook

Tags: facebook, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, sharing, open-graph

Check out this URL:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.linuxstall.com

Everything is fine except the last line which is

Note: "Reference in Perl" is the most recent post at my site.

When I share any of my post on facebook then it works fine but when I share the homepage ([www.linuxstall.com](http://www.linuxstall.com)) then it shows most recent post's description instead of the site's description.

What is the reason of that? How can I correct that?

I have configured open graph using YOAST.

[image]

See the screenshot. It is showing "Reference in Perl" as a description.

Comment: Can you link to the plugin you are using. Chances are it has to do with that. I see "Reference in Perl" is the most recent article and I'm sure that's what the Open graph is pulling because it's just guessing on content.

Comment: I got it. JETPACK's sharing option is the reason for this. I don't want to remove JETPACK but I want to remove this sharing feature. How can I do that? I mean how to disable this feature. I don't use its sharing option in posts BTW but it still giving the description.

Comment: I have done it. Problem solved :)

Comment: Yes, the problem is with Jetpack sharing. Chankey, how did you fix it?

Comment: I turned off the jetpack sharing option.

Answer (score 4):

In the source code I see two *og:description* meta tags. The first and correct one seems to be coming from your Yoast WordPress SEO Plugin. The other one is outside the plugin's block, so I guess it's defined elsewhere.

Check your theme if it includes that meta tag. If not, check your other plugins. Disable them one by one to find the culprit.

Comment: I searched all theme files for the text "og:description" but didn't find it in any file. Will you please let me know where will it be so that I can edit that?

Comment: Most likely you would find this in the header.php oder functions.php file of your theme.
Can you provide a list of all activated plugins on your blog? Chances are high that one might also add these tags, not only Yoast's plugin.

Comment: akismet, authors widget, easy mashable social bar, jetpack, RDFa breadcrump, seo smart links, TimThumb, Whydowork adsense, Wpfirewall2, Yoast, wp-note, wp-polls, wp-syntax, wp-terminal.

Comment: I got it. JETPACK's sharing option is the reason for this. I don't want to remove JETPACK but I want to remove this sharing feature. How can I do that? I mean how to disable this feature. I don't use its sharing option in posts BTW but it still giving the description.

Comment: I have done it. Problem solved :)